# Are services included in the calculation of a trade deficit?

Tags: international-trade, balance-of-trade

Are services included in the calculation of a trade deficit?

Presumably measuring service exports is more difficult/less accurate(?) than for goods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is that they are. For example, see the current report on the trade in goods and services for the United States: [link to BEA website; latest report.](https://www.bea.gov/data/intl-trade-investment/international-trade-goods-and-services)